# Convert data source UICollectionView to CSV file

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, export-to-csv

I search how to convert `UICollectionView` to `CSV` file and send it with Mail. 
I have a collection view like the photo and I want to export the table and send it. I search and found that the best way is to convert to `CSV` file.
If you have other suggestion, just tell me.

[image]

Comment: Don't convert your UICollectionView, convert the dataSource (array or dictionary used to populate it) of your UICollectionView.

Comment: Yes converting to CSV is one way, or else if editing is not a criteria, then can take screen shot and can send the image in mail

Comment: @Larme i now the dataSource of the CollectionView But how i did it ... i don't find func in swift to convert the data source to CSV File .

Comment: @Janmenjaya I don't think the screen shot is the best way because a have more column . that why search a solution for convert data source of collection view to file CSV or other ??

Comment: @AhmedAmine, You can take full screen shot, it is possible to take screen shot of the whole content of a scrollable view. But only thing is you cannot edit like you can in CSV

Comment: @Janmenjaya yes with screen i can not edit the values ... that's why i wan't to convert CSV file ... you don't know how i did it ??

Comment: csv is just a string file of strings with separator (usually comma). If you don't say how the final csv file should look like and how your datasource look like, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larme has pointed out, converting this to a CSV file has nothing to do with the visual representation in the collection view. You simply need to parse the data source to CSV. CSV stands for Comma Separated Value, which in turn means a type of file where tabular data is encoded using a delimiter between each data point (this is generally a comma, but could be anything), and a new line for each line of the table. Think of the delimiter as the vertical line between each column of the table, and the new line as the row:

So your CSV text file might look like this:

```
 TITLEFORCOLUMN1, TITLEFORCOLUMN2, TITLEFORCOLUMN3
 ROWTITLEONE, 200, 300
 ROWTITLETWO, 400, 500
```

and so on. It's not quite this simple, and there are rules that you should follow, especially if you intend the CSV file to be consumed by third parties. There is an official specification which you can look at, but you can also get a lot of tips by searching 'CSV file specification'.

You then need to create a string by iterating through your data source. Start off by creating the line specifying the headers, then add a newline character and then add your data. So for the above example you could do something like (assuming the data is set out as a two dimensional array)

```
var myCSVString : String = "TITLEFORCOLUMN1, TITLEFORCOLUMN2, TITLEFORCOLUMN3\n"
for lineItem in myDataSource {
    myCSVString = myCSVString + lineItem[0] + ", " + lineItem[1] + ", " + lineItem[2] + "\n"
}
```

Then write the string to file.

You'll need to do more research yourself but hopefully that will set you off in the right direction.